# How can I compare the number of irreducible factors of one element with another?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ an UFD and $a,b,c \in R$ be such that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and noninvertible. Suppose $a = bc$. How can I show that the number of irreducible factors of $a$ is greater than or equal to the number of irreducible factors of $b$?

I could easily check that for the case where $c$ is not invertible, the above holds.

Let $n(x)$ be the number of irreducible factors of the element $x$.

Let us note that $n(c) \geq 1 \geq 0$, then $n(b)+n(c) \geq n(b)$ and since $a = bc$, $n(a) = n(b)+n(c) \geq n(b)$.

But for the case where $c$ is invertible, it is not so clear to me how the above fact is satisfied. I have only been able to think that $a$ will have another decomposition into product of irreducible factors in which it differs from an invertible factor (can I claim in this situation that $n(a) = n(bc)$?), which in this case is $c$.

Comment: Invertible elements are units. Then $a$ and $b$ are associate, so they have the same number of irreducible factors. For example, $a=2x^2-2$ and $b=x^2-1$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$ with invertible element $c=2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ok. I understand the example.  But, why if $a$ and $b$ are associated, can we conclude that they have the same number of irreducible factors?

Comment: Because they differ only by a unit. From wikipedia. "The irreducible factors of an element are uniquely defined, up to the multiplication by a unit, if the integral domain is a unique factorization domain.".

Comment: To be precise, you should clarify if you are counting factors by equality or by associates, i.e. are all associate factors counted only once?